# Fallacy considering a relation between infinite sets and empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Namely I have stumbled upon a theorem due to Dedekind which says:

A set is infinite iff it is equinumerous to a proper subeset of itself

Since empty set is proper subset of every set except itself it implies that any infinite set A is equinumerous to empty set.Thus we could conclude that every infinite set has cardinality 0

Did I misunderstand something?Is there a special case for definition of proper subsets when we are dealing with empty set

If this hypothesis is valid I assume we should restate the theorem to :

A set is infinite iff it is equinumerous to every non-empty proper subset of itself

Comment: Your restatement would not be correct. The "a" in the original statement does not mean "all".

Comment: Ah the little catches of mathematics,thats what makes me love it

Comment: I don't see how this is a catch. You mistook "a" for "every". While it's somewhat understandable mistake in some cases, it's not a catch of any kind.

Comment: Not that it is a trick,but it is something that can go easily unnoticed,especially when drowsy

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't say that an infinite set is equinumerous to *every* proper subset of itself.

What it says that if a set is infinite, then there will exist *some* proper subset that is equinumerous to it.

For example, $\mathbb Z$ is infinite, and is equinumerous to its proper subset $\mathbb N$. But it is not equinumerous to $\{1,2,3\}$ even though $\{1,2,3\}$ is also a proper subset.